# Spring MVC: Required Date parameter 'date' is not present

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm writing a web application using Spring MVC. In my jsp is a form which content is send with Ajax to my controller. 
The simplified code for the mapped method looks:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String filter(@RequestParam(required=false) Date createdTo) { }
```

I have registered CustomDateEditor with:

```
@InitBinder
public void registerBinders(WebDataBinder binder){
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(format, true));
}
```

When the String in the form input is correct no exception is thrown.
The problem is that, when the input for date is empty or contains String that can't be converted to date, I get exception:  `Required Date parameter 'createdTo' is not present`.

I've even written my own DateEditor and during debugging it, I've noticed that the problem occurs when the editor sets returned value to null with `setValue(null)`.
When I changed the code so the returned value is the current date `setValue(new Date())` everything works even for empty Strings.

Why my mapped method doesn't allow to have `@RequestParam(required=false) Date createdTo' null value? 
Why is it so and how can I fox it?

The request is send with:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '<c:url value="/admin/documents/filter"/>',
data: data
}).done(doneFunction);
```

The controller code is:

```
@Controller
```

@RequestMapping("/admin/documents")
public class AdminDocumentsController extends BaseController {

```
@InitBinder
public void registerBinders(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new DateEditor());
}

@RequestMapping(value = { "", "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showDocuments(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("so", new DocumentsSearchOptions());
    return "admin/documents";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/filter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> filter(@RequestParam String number,
        @RequestParam String invoiceNumber,
        @RequestParam String userSurname, @RequestParam(required=false) Double fromPrice,
        @RequestParam(required=false) Double toPrice, @RequestParam(required=false) Integer fromPoints,
        @RequestParam(required=false) Integer toPoints, @RequestParam String createdFrom,
        @RequestParam(required=false) Date createdTo, @RequestParam String invoiceFrom,
        @RequestParam String invoiceTo, @RequestParam String paidFrom,
        @RequestParam String paidTo) {

    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();

    return model;
}
```

Dates and object wrappers throw `MissingServletRequestParameterException` when their corresponding input fields are left empty.

Comment: What is the content of the DATA variable on your ajax post?

Comment: I've tried two send data in two types:
a) `var data = $('#form').serialize()` and then it looked something like `param1=&param2=&param3=`
b) reading each input separetly and creating a data object:
`var param1 = $('#param1).val();
var param2 = $('#param2).val();
var data = {
param1: param1,
param2: param2
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception you get (`MissingServletRequestParameterException`) is really only thrown when a parameter is required, but not present. The parameter can even be empty.

Moreover binding happens **after** the parameter check. That means when you get the exception it's **before** the custom editor is called.

The problem must be related to another method. Maybe you redirect in the `filter`method.

Comment: During debugging I've noticed that the exception is thrown after line `setValue(null)` so it seems like the biding was before check. What's more, the is no redirecting in the method.

Comment: Set a breakpoint for `MissingServletRequestParameterException`, then you know when it happens :) Oh, what version of Spring do you use? What I wrote could indeed be wrong for earlier versions.

Comment: I'm using Spring 3.2.3.
So why am I able to go into binding method before exception is thrown?

Comment: Please, set the breakpoint and you will see. You know, I can only guess, but you can actually check it out :)

Comment: Well, I guess it's because of my lack of experience with debugging exceptions but I didn't get any useful information with this breakpoint. But it is right that exception is thrown before binding method. However, I still have no idea why it doesn't work. I could go around and change all @RequestParam's to String and then convert them in the Controller method, however, it woldn't be a nice solution

Comment: When the breakpoint hits check the variable `paramName` - should be `createdTo`. In the `Debug` view, where you can see the call stack, click on the lowest `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and check the variable `handler` - should be `public String AdminDocumentsController.filter(your parameters)`

Comment: Everything is exactly as you said.

Comment: I found a way around by assigning a ModelAttribute to the form, serialize it in the Ajax call and then accept in in my filter method. In such case empty inputs set corresponding values of ModelAttribute to null :)